# Ito isometry of variance of integral on interval [t, t+1]

Tags: expected

Can I use Ito isometry to calculate $Var(Y_t)$ where $Y_t= \int_{t}^{t+1}B_sdB_s$ and $B_s$ is Brownian motion, in this way? Is my reasoning correct?
$$Var(Y_t)=E[Y_t^2]-(E[Y_t])^2$$
Applying Ito isometry

$E[\int_{t}^{t+1}B_sdB_s]^2=E[\int_{t}^{t+1}B_s^2ds]=\int_{t}^{t+1}E[B_s^2]ds=\int_{t}^{t+1}sds=\ldots=t+\frac{1}{2}$

Knowing that $E[B_t]=0$
$$(E[\int_{t}^{t+1}B_sdB_s])^2=(\int_{t}^{t+1}E[B_s]dB_s)^2=0$$

$$Var(Y_t)=t+\frac{1}{2}?$$

Comment: this is correct